# create matrix with columns populated from vector values and row names from a different vector values

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector, datatable

i have this data...

```
df <-structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2014L, 2012L, 2014L, 2014L), 
               NODCCODE = c(110040218L, 121053801L, 170281801L, 170281801L, 170281801L), 
               Number = c(1,  5, 2, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
df
   year   NODCCODE Number
1: 2017 110040218    1
2: 2014 121053801    5
3: 2012 170281801    2
4: 2014 170281801    2
5: 2014 170281801    4
```

I'd like to create this for a much larger data set

```
df3 <- structure(list(year = c(2012L, 2014L, 2017L), 
               `110040218` = c(0L, 0L, 1L), 
               `121053801` = c(2L, 5L, 0L), 
               `170281801` = c(2L, 3L, 0L)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

df3
   year 110040218 121053801 170281801
1: 2012         0         2         2
2: 2014         0         5         3
3: 2017         1         0         0
```

I made the second table manually so let me explain in case I screwed it up. I have the three starting vectors, which all have many repeated values. I want the column names to be the NODCCODE numbers iterated only once, so no repeats. The first column will by consecutive years populated from the year column, but also not repeating. To populate the matrix I want to use the Number values, but if the year and NODCCODE number match then it needs to take the average and put that in that cell of the matrix.

My starting data is number of fish caught per net. So I have many species (NODCCODE code) records for each year. My actual data can be found here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LTxZhD00QvFbioLPiOJMLjm5MftOmbZt/view?usp=sharing  if that is more helpful. There are many nets set and the same species are caught in many of them each year. 
The final matrix if using the whole data set, should have years 2008-2018 sequentially in the first column (only one row per year). And something like 136-138 NODCODES as the rest of the column names.

So in other words its going to be a very short but very wide matrix with year as column 1. the rest of the columns will be unique NODCCODE (species). The value for each one will be an average of all the values for that NODCCODE (species) and year combinations.

I've tried many ways to do this including group by and the following code:

```
test <- gather(test, NODCCODE, Number, -year) %>% arrange(year, NODCCODE)
```

But I keep getting results that are not even close.

I've probably over complicated this so hopefully my example data helps. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a long to wide format conversion. You can do that using `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(data = df,
      formula = year ~ NODCCODE, 
      value.var = "Number",
      # Function to aggregate multiple matches
      fun.aggregate = mean,
      # Fill missing values with zeros
      fill = 0)

#    year 110040218 121053801 170281801
# 1: 2012         0         0         2
# 2: 2014         0         5         3
# 3: 2017         1         0         0
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! I'd upvote you twice for the super quick reply to my overly confusing question if I could!!! lol

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2014L, 2012L, 2014L, 2014L), 
                    NODCCODE = c(110040218L, 121053801L, 170281801L, 170281801L, 170281801L), 
                    Number = c(1,  5, 2, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
df <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = NODCCODE,
              values_from = Number, 
              values_fn = list(Number = mean))

df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Function `gather` has been retired in `tidyr` and has been replaced with `pivot_wider`. We need the argument `values_fn` as we otherwise would end up with nested vector for some of the list elements. `values_fn` allows us to apply a function to each element after changing shape.

With this output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   year `110040218` `121053801` `170281801`
  <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2017           1           0           0
2  2014           0           5           3
3  2012           0           0           2
```

UPDATE

`pivot_wider` comes with an argument to deal with missing values: `values_fill`:

```
df <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = NODCCODE,
              values_from = Number, 
              values_fn = list(Number = mean),
              values_fill = list(Number = 0))
```

Comment: Another very good answer, Jonathan just beat you by a few seconds. Thank you for the quick response and the very good answer as well! upvotes for you too.